# My WordPress installation isn't updating the feed when a new post is published

Tags: rss, feed

My WordPress installation was working quite well, however it recently stopped properly updating feeds when new posts are published. I may have deleted a tranistent feed table using the Clean Options WordPress plugin. I don't know if that's the cause, but I can force it to update by changing one of the Feed settings manually each time.

How can I get it working properly again?

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have some kind of caching enabled?

Comment: What feeds exactly you are referring to?

Comment: It fails to update RSS2, RSS, Atom, and RDF feeds. Say I just post an article right now. The feed will only show the items from before then. Not the just-posted story. If I go tweak a feed setting, it then gets flushed and works. But I have to do that each time. I am using W3 Total Cache.

Answer (score 1):

Do you refer to *feed settings* in WordPress or W3 Total Cache?

Since I think this is indeed likely to be caching issue I'd check following:

1. Check that feed is not getting stuck in browser cache (force reload, clear cache and reload).
2. Verify that headers on feed make sense, http://redbot.org/ is good tool.
3. Try to disable feed caching in `Performance > Page Cache` and see if it makes a difference.
4. Enable debug mode for page cache in `Performance > General Settings` and look through information it gives on feeds.

Comment: I was having the exact same problems and making sure that feeds weren't being cached in W3 Total Cache worked for me!  Thanks so much for the help!